# How to restore OS X on MacBook Air after installing Windows 8?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

After installing Windows 8 MacBook Air is not booting. I want to revert back to  OS X. I need help on how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

press the Option key + R
select the disk that installed
Mac OSx.
maybe you're starting with
Windows.

Now if you want to
a new installation, you will
need access to another Mac,
to mount the flash drive installation.
follow these steps: http://osxdaily.com/2015/09/30/create-os-x-el-capitan-boot-install-drive/

Comment: Please improve your answer: boot to Recovery Mode/Internet Recovery Mode -> Disk Utility -> Check / Erase Volume/Disk -> Restore OS X

Comment: Because improving my answer? I told him
does not work? it can not mount a USB stick
installation on another computer
and reinstall the system?

Comment: Because your answer is incomplete and frowsy. The first half of the first sentence is the right direction. In case the OP has no second mac/no thumb drive there is still a solution like indicated in my comment.

Comment: at the moment it does not have a connection to the internet your solution does not work well.